# Problems with Preview-ing ps and ps2pdf output on OS X

Tags: eps, mac, postscript

after upgrading to OS X 10.8.x I've discovered that Preview stopped displaying some of my eps pictures. Also, ps2pdf output is now broken. Have anybody seen such behaviour and does anybody know how to work around / fix it?

I'm using MacTeX 2010 and here are some screenshots:

OSX 10.7.x

[image]

OS X 10.8

[image]

Fedora Core 17 (proper display)

[image]

Update: link to the offending eps file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1828464/torus.eps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your post to display the pictures inline. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Otherwise it's pretty tough to troubleshoot.

Comment: @dhst Thanks! I've added a link to the bad eps to the question.

Comment: I can confirm the output you got with OS X 10.8 and Fedora 17. My guess is that there might be something anomalous with the file header which is confusing Preview on how to properly render the output (converting your `eps` to `pdf` gives me the same wrong result). I've seen something along these lines in the past. Could you tell us more about the software you used to generate that specific `.eps` image? Maybe we can find some clues on what is happening. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thanks for the reply. The eps is the output of asymptote. I do have the source code but it is not compatible with the current asymptote version. I'm trying to convert it but so many things have changed, that I'm completely lost :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about issues with Preview rather than TeX _per se_.